# ng-view в Angularjs ничего не выводит

Tags: angularjs

Пытаюсь сделать простейший роутинг, вместо него в разметке присутствует только комментарий `<!-- ngView: -->` без div-а, что я делаю не так?

Разметка:

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
  <head lang="ru">
    <script src="vendor/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="page-nav_item">
        <a href="/create" class="page-nav__item-link">Наши сервисы</a>
      </li>
      <li class="page-nav_item">
        <a href="/about" class="page-nav__item-link">О компании</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view></div>

    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="vendor/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- Begin: Source JS -->
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.config.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->
  </body>
</html>
```

app.module.js:

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('myApp', [
   'ngMaterial',
   'ngMessages',
   'ngRoute',
 ]);
```

config.js:

```
 'use strict';

 angular
   .module('myApp')
     .config(['$routeProvider',
       function($routeProvider) {

       $routeProvider
         .when('/create', {
           template: '<h1>Create</h1>'
         })
        .when('/about', {
          template: '<h1>About</h1>'
        })
      }
   ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил, я использовал версию angular 1.6.3 и здесь https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8 сказано, что изменён hashPrefix. Итак 2 ошибки:

1. config.js изменить на:

```js
'use strict';
      angular
        .module('mindMapApp')
          .config(['$locationProvider','$routeProvider',
            function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
              $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

              $routeProvider
                .when('/create', {
                   template: '<h1>Create</h1>'
                })
                .when('/about', {
                   template: '<h1>About</h1>'
                })
             }
         ]);
```

Добавив $locationProvider и значение по умолчания в качестве префикса.

2. В ссылках нужно указывать адрес со знаком хэш (по умолчанию со знаком #!)

   `<a href="#/create" class="page-nav__item-link">Наши сервисы</a>` вместо
   `<a href="/create" class="page-nav__item-link">Наши сервисы</a>`